# SKPhysicsBody, rotate a sprite after applying impulse to change direction

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am looking for some info on how I can get my sprite to change its rotation by changing the angle of the sprite.

Basically here is how it is set up.  Imagine a rocket that is sitting in a stationary position.  The physics body is the shape of the rocket, with the tip pointing to the top.  Now I apply an immediate impulse to the rocket to send it into the air.  While in the air,  I would like to use the accelerometer to rotate the sprite.  With the rotation, I am expecting the direction of the sprite to change.  Unfortunately, The sprite goes straight up and down instead of the direction it is rotated, even though the texture and physics body is rotated. I am having a hard time trying to find info on what techniques are used to achieve the results I want.  Most examples have a continuous force,  but I only have the initial force with no change after that.  I have played around with linearDamping and angularDamping, but that was no help. I have also tried attaching another physics body to the tip to make the tip more heavy to see if the direction will change, but that didn't help either. My only work around that worked is to change the gravity direction,  But I would like to avoid this. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand, you're using the accelerometer to rotate the sprite, which is working, but there's no sideways impulse on the spite to give it sideways movement. You'd also like the amount of sideways movement to correspond with the rotation of the Sprite, so it looks natural. Why don't you use the accelerometer to apply a force to the Sprite (the force is applied whilst the device is tilted) and then rotate the Sprite manually to match its new velocity vector?

Comment: A force or impulse to a physics body is, by default, applied to the centre of mass, causing no rotation, but they can also be applied to a specified point in the body, which might cause the rotation and sideways movement in one go. You could apply the force/impulse at the base to simulate the gimballing of the engines.

Comment: You can calculate the magnitude of the current velocity and then update the velocity based on the accelerometer's x and y multiply by the magnitude.

Comment: @SteveIves I do not want to apply any more force than what is given

Comment: @Epsilon, we have thought of that, it is an option, but we are wondering if there was something that involves actual physics that could achieve this.  We just do not understand why when the rocket is not at a 45 degree angle, the rocket does not change direction,  wouldn't the air resistance cause the direction to change?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - I agree, but could you not try applying the force differently? If you apply only a single force at take-off, and the body then rotates about it's centre of mess, I don't think you can expect it to change direction. That would imply an acceleration and that requires a force that you haven't applied. You mention air resistance - that's not something SpriteKit simulates and I'm not sure it would cause a change of direction anyway.

Comment: @SteveIves best way I can think about it is throwing a paper airplane,  I do not want other forces affecting the throw.  But that plane does not travel in the same direction as I threw it, it curves.  Something causes it to curve, and how could I achieve it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - hmm, interesting. So you want to simulate air flowing over the control surfaces of an (unpowered) plane, causing a change in attitude. You're going to have to cheat, and apply a force to represent the effects of that airflow, but in such a way that the speed doesn't change.

Comment: @SteveIves I want the speed to reduce

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - OK - that's probably easier. You're going to have to give the rocket movable control surfaces (or simulate them) and simulate air resistance.  I think you want to check out how a flight physics of a guided bomb work.

Comment: So to make the rocket both turn left and to actually go left, try applying a force to the right at the base of the rocket and another force to the left (this will be to the centre of mass). This should cause the rocket to rotate about it's centre of mass and accelerate to the left.  But there's nothing to ensure that the new direction of the rocket will match it's rotation  I think you need to cheat - rotate the rocket and then slowly manually change it's velocity property until it matches it's rotation.

Comment: My understanding is that SpriteKit's physics engine applies air resistance to the physics body without regard to the shape of the body so turning will not affect the trajectory. That said, I suggest you calculate the magnitude of the velocity with `mag = sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy)`; the normalized accelerometer's direction by `dx = x / (x+y)` and `dy = y / (x+y)`; and the new velocity vector with `v = CGVectorMake (mag * dx, mag * dy)`.

Comment: @Epsilon, thank you for the formula,  like I have said, we have already thought of that approach, but using sqrt can be taxing,  besides,we are really experimenting with the actual physics engine, so we are trying to avoid cheats and manipulations to it.  If there is no way to alter the force based on the shape, then perhaps there is nothing we can do.  Btw  I have also tried adding mass to the head of the rocket,  so that when you tilt more mass is on one side than the other,  but that didn't get the results I wanted either

Comment: @Knight0fDragon is there any particular reason why you want to achieve the change in velocity of the rocket via accurate physics simulation, but you're happy to 'cheat' with the rotation of the rocket i.e. Rotate it directly based upon accelerometer input? Why not just change the velocity manually to match the rotation?

Comment: it is not cheating, the accelerometer applies will be applying angular force to spin the rocket.  I do not want to change the velocity manually because I want to achieve a more organic feel to the game

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you may be looking for is in Sprite Kits **SKFieldNode** class.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/linearGravityFieldWithVector:

The **linearGravityFieldWithVector:** is probably your best bet. It applies a linear gravity field in a direction you set.

You can also check out **electricField** which is similar however you can change the charge to positive or negative.

Comment: hmm, this may work with my changing gravity work around, instead of changing gravity for the entire world, I could slap the field under it and rotate the field to be perpendicular to the rocket, in a way that the direction is always moving in a downwards thrust.  This sprite would have to ignore the physicsworld gravity though

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I am having a bit trouble trying to visualize what you're explaining, however you should go and check out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsBody/applyAngularImpulse: this function applies an Angular Impulse which could help? Like I said I'm not entirely sure exactly what your describing

Comment: angular impulse is for when you want to create a pin wheel style effect, it will not change the trajectory.  To clarify my comment,  Going straight up, gravity gives me a downward force,  If I then steer the rocket 45 degrees left,  I expect the rocket to travel 45 degrees in the left direction,  so if I rotate the gravity 45 degrees right,  it should be pushing the rocket to the left